# Gurobi-Python with set

Tags: python, set, linear-programming, gurobi

So I am trying to solve an optimization problem using Python-Gurobi link but the problem is that I am stuck in the first step!

We have two set of M={1,2,3} and N={1,2}

We have a set that is called S_i. This S_i can be either empty, or {1} or {2} or {1,2}. It means that for each i, S can only be one of the potential combinations of the set N.
We have a variable X_S_i. It means that if X is 1, we select one of the possible forms of S to assign to i.
I am trying to solve the model in the picture attached but I dont know how to define a variable with a set attached to it.
Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: This is called a "power set".

Comment: The model in the image doesn't make much sense to me. What's the meaning of M and as I understand it there is only one constriant, thereby all except one of the x_i is zero. This means that you can just choose the x_i with the largest r_ij to maximize the objective. Also the powerset is unordered but you try to assign the r_ij to a speciifc x_i for i in the power set?

Comment: And next time, please put the formulas directly into your question.

Comment: Hi @mattmilten. Very keen observation with the answer and the use of largest r_ij but i used this formulation as an example to learn about how to model these problems in python. The real problem is very complicated to solve but if I learn the general way, i think I can do it myself. You are right about the constraint. But it is true for each i. This means that we have several x_s_i equal to one. Please note that the variable is x_s_i. My problem is with the definition of x_s_i not r_ij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is example code for generating variables (I assume that this is done using `model.addVar()`) based on a power set. The power set generator is copied from here: https://www.technomancy.org/python/powerset-generator-python/

```
def powerset(seq):
    """
    Returns all the subsets of this set. This is a generator.
    """
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        yield seq
        yield []
    else:
        for item in powerset(seq[1:]):
            yield [seq[0]]+item
            yield item

variables = []
for x in powerset([1, 2, 3]):
    variables.append(model.addVar())
```